# Continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ standard topology to $\mathbb{R}_l$ lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, sorgenfrey-line

The 2nd chapter of Topology by Munkres discussed the identity function
$$
f: \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_l
$$
from $\mathbb{R}$ (with standard topology) to $\mathbb{R}_l$ (with lower limit topology).

The book reads: the inverse image of the open set $[a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}_l$ equals itself, which is not open in  $\mathbb{R}$.

My questions:

(1) How the identity function can map from $(a,b)$ to $[a,b)$? since $a\notin (a,b)$ but $a\in [a,b)$.

(2) Why the inverse image of the open set $[a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}_l$ equals itself? I think the inverse image should be $(a,b)$, which is the "opposite" situation that $f$ maps from $[a,b)$ to $(a,b)$.

Comment: Did you mean the *identity* function, which maps anything to itself?  $\mathbb R_l$ has a different topology from $\mathbb R$ with standard topology, but the same underlying set

Comment: I don't have that book. Where does the author say that the identity function maps $(a,b)$ to $[a,b)$? It's not in the passage you quoted. And where do you get the idea that "$\{a\}$ is not included in $\mathbb R$"? If $a$ is a real number, and $\mathbb R$ is the set of all real numbers, then of course $\{a\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Comment: dear bof, thanks for your comments. The two questions reflect my confusion, which are not from the book. I have edited the first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the *identity* function he discusses, i.e. $f(x)=x$, which is a well-defined function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R_l$ because both spaces have the same elements (all real numbers). And of course $a \in \Bbb R$. Maybe the arbitrary $a$ and $b$ confuse you? To show $f$ is *not* continuous it is enough to find *one* open set in $\Bbb R_l$ such that $f^{-1}[O]$ is *not open* in $\Bbb R$. I'll take $O=[0,1)$ for definiteness, which is open in $\Bbb R_l$ by definition.

Recall that $f^{-1}[[0,1)]= \{x \in \Bbb R \mid f(x) \in [0,1)\} = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x \in [0,1)\} = [0,1)$ and $[0,1)$ is *not* open in $\Bbb R$ as no open interval that contains $0$ sits inside $[0,1)$ so that $0$ is not an interior point of $[0,1)$ in $\Bbb R$.

So we are done showing $f$ non-continuous.
Note that inverse images of the identity function are very simple: $f^{-1}[O]=O$ for all $O$. And also $f[O]=O$.

Answer (score 1):

The image of $(a,b)$ under the map $f$ is $(a,b)$ and not $[a,b)$ since $$f((a,b))=\{y \in \mathbb{R}:y=f(x) (\exists x \in (a,b))\}=\{y \in \mathbb{R}:y=x (\exists x \in (a,b))\}=(a,b).$$

Note that $$f^{-1}([a,b))=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x)\in [a,b)\}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x\in [a,b)\}=[a,b).$$

Therefore, $f^{-1}([a,b))=[a,b)$.